# CRON jobs sending email, but I didn't configured it

Tags: cron, email

I'm always taking a look on the logs to see anything suspicious. But, I only noticed today those logs:

`Aug  3 06:32:10 nori-hidamari anacron[1234]: Job 'cron.daily' terminated (mailing output)`
`Aug  3 06:32:10 nori-hidamari anacron[1234]: Job 'cron.weekly' started`
`Aug  3 06:32:10 nori-hidamari postfix/sendmail[3443]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory`
`Aug  3 06:32:10 nori-hidamari anacron[1234]: Tried to mail output of job 'cron.daily', but mailer process (/usr/sbin/sendmail) exited with status 75`

Strangely, I never made any change on any cron file. Even if it's not sending an e-mail, is this a normal behaviour of a cron with default configurations?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: if the cron jobs do any *output* that is mailed.  just redirect to a file or do as i do and launch the jobs in `screen`.

Comment: @Skaperen I don't know if I explained well. My question is if trying to send e-mails is something activated by default in cron.

Comment: @Skaperen I just noticed that it only happens sometimes, and it trying to send since some time ago (aprox. 1 month). Maybe it's really something turned on by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default email will be sent either to whatever is specified by the MAILTO variable or to the crontab owner, and that every time there is a cron job output. From the cron(8) man page:

*cron wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, checking each command to see if it should be run in the current minute.  When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the crontab, if such exists).*

However you seem to have a config problem with postfix/sendmail or, perhaps more precisely, with yr postfix to sendmail compatibility interface. It does not seem to be correctly configured.

If you want to understand what the exit status 75 means look [this](http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/sendmail/ch36_05.htm) up:

> *EX_TEMPFAIL A Recoverable Error: The **EX_TEMPFAIL exit code (value 75)**
>   is returned by sendmail to indicate that a temporary error has
>   occurred. Temporary errors mean that the mail message will be put in
>   (or remain in) the queue for the present, and another delivery attempt
>   will be made later.*

To reconfigure `postfix`, do, from the cmd line:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

That ought to solve your problem, provided postfix was correctly installed.

To determine the location of the directory that contains your Postfix `main.cf` and `master.cf` config files, do, from cmd-line:

```
$ postconf config_directory
```

Check yr config files out to see that yr configuration is correct.

For the sake of completeness, you should know that Postfix has also a log procedure in case config-debugging is needed. On my box (Trusty LTS) its log file is located at `/var/log/mail.log`. In the log look for keywords as quoted from `/usr/share/doc/postfix/DEBUG_README`:

> - "panic" indicates a problem in the software itself that only a programmer
>     can fix. Postfix cannot proceed until this is fixed.
> - "fatal" is the result of missing files, incorrect permissions,
>     incorrect
>     configuration file settings that you can fix. Postfix cannot proceed until
>     this is fixed.
> - "error" reports an error condition. For safety reasons, a Postfix
>     process
>     will terminate when more than 13 of these happen.
> - "warning" indicates a non-fatal error. These are problems that you
>     may not
>     be able to fix (such as a broken DNS server elsewhere on the network) but
>     may also indicate local configuration errors that could become a problem
>     later.

If this does not give you what you need to make the problem go away, you'll have to go deeper using debugging tools available to you on Ubuntu to determine where the problem lies. I think that falls outside the scope of yr question.